# How to get dragged items into grid?

Tags: apache-flex

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg1" dataProvider="{cNumbersList}" cornerRadius="3" 
    allowMultipleSelection="true" 
    change="selectedItem=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.contactName;
            selectedSno=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.contactNo;"
    dropEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dragEnabled="true" 
    fontWeight="normal">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactName" headerText="Name"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactNo" 
                headerText="ContactNo"/>                
        </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

<mx:DataGrid id="dg2" cornerRadius="3" allowMultipleSelection="true" 
    visible="false" dataProvider="{}" dropEnabled="true" 
    dragMoveEnabled="true" dragEnabled="true" fontWeight="normal">

    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactName" headerText="Name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactNo"
            headerText="ContactNo"/>                
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

How can I get all dragged items in to second grid(dg2)?

Comment: Are you looking for "How to drag and drop items from one `DataGrid` to another `DataGrid` in Flex?"

Comment: @vasu - In future, select the code and hit Ctrl-K - And indent the code so that it is easily readable.

Comment: @Amarghosh : above u said thing is not working...giving error
below i sent piece of code,in that two snippets,i want all items of target ,how can i get,

Comment: Are you actually using flex builder? How do u manage to take your code indentation to such messy levels?

Comment: @Amarghosh : leave abt that code indentation yar,tell me the idea to get all dropped items from one list/grid in below code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to access the items dropped into `dg2` from `dg1`, here is how to do that:

```
var list:ListCollectionView = dg2.dataProvider;
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
  trace(list.getItemAt(i));
```

Btw, something tells me that this is wrong:

```
change="selectedItem=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.contactName;
selectedSno=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.contactNo;"
```

What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: @Amarghosh : above u said thing is not working...giving error below i sent piece of code,in that two snippets,i want all items of target ,how can i get,

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:HBox>

         <mx:List id="List1" dataProvider="{grpList}" labelField="groupName" dragMoveEnabled="true" dragEnabled="true" allowMultipleSelection="true" dropEnabled="true" width="120" />
         <mx:VBox>
            <mx:Label text="Selected Groups :"  width="122" color="#C90855"/>        
            <mx:List id="List2" dropEnabled="true" labelField="groupName" dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" allowMultipleSelection="true" dataProvider="{selectedGroupsListArray}" width="120"  height="111" borderColor="#0A8AE4"/>
        </mx:VBox>       
        </mx:HBox>
```

---

```
<mx:HBox>        
             <mx:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{cNumbersList}" cornerRadius="3" allowMultipleSelection="true" 
                change="selectedItem=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.contactName;selectedSno=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.contactNo;"
                    dropEnabled="true"  dragMoveEnabled="true"  dragEnabled="true" fontWeight="normal" height="163">
                   <mx:columns>
                       <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactName" headerText="Name"/>
                       <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactNo" headerText="ContactNo"/>                
                   </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>
            <mx:VBox>
                <mx:Label text="Selected Contacts :"  width="122" color="#C90855" height="16"/>
                <mx:DataGrid id="selectedContsList" cornerRadius="3" allowMultipleSelection="true" 
                 dropEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dragEnabled="true" fontWeight="bold" borderColor="#066EB7" height="144">
                   <mx:columns>
                       <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactName" headerText="Name"/>
                       <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contactNo" headerText="ContactNo"/>                
                   </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>

            </mx:VBox>          

        </mx:HBox>
```