# using drag & dop into list,how can i get list items in flex

Tags: apache-flex

while i using drag & drop from listbox1 to listbox2 ,how can i get all the items of listbox2 in flex

Comment: how about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782754/how-to-get-dragged-items-into-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip:
Add an empty dataProvider on listbox2. Your dropped Items will appear there.

Or you can try this:

```
for(var i:int = 0;i < listbox2.numChildren;i++)
{
        var theChild:Object = listbox2.getChildAt(i);
}
```